# Faces-redirect as default for Links?

Tags: java, jsf, jboss

can I somehow configure JSF, Jboss to default use `?faces-redirect=true` for every link?
Or do I have to specify this for each link I'm writing?

ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect suffix `?faces-redirect=true`is only needed if you want to make a GET request after a POST, e.g. from a backing bean action method. For "normal" links via GET you should use `h:link` or `h:button` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify <redirect/> in the navigation cases in faces-config.xml.